# Reset password Oracle database 18c

Tags: oracle, oracle-18c, password-recovery

I have installed Oracle databases 18c. I forgot the account administrator of the databases, how to recover the password?

```
SP2-0640: Not connected
SQL> conn XEPDB1
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a connection using OS authentication and change whatever is needed. For this it is in most cases needed to logon to the database server with an account that is a member of the dba group (or whatever group was specified during the installation).

Set your ORACLE_SID, ORACLE_HOME en PATH variables correctly and connect using

`sqlplus / as sysdba`